# LEVEL BY LEVEL of a Tree with Java

Tags: java, tree

How can I get all the elements of a Tree?

```
public static <E> PositionList<E> width(Tree<E> t){
    //I've initialized a queue and a PositionList<E>
    Queue<E> aux =  new NodeQueue<E>();
    PositionList<E> positionAux =  new NodePositionList<E>();
Position<E> pointer = t.root();
```

...

but then I don't know how to continue...

Example:

```
     1
    |  |
    2   3
   | |  | |
   4  5  6 7
```

Return a list [1,2,3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Printing a Binary Tree using Level-Order in a Specific Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241513/java-printing-a-binary-tree-using-level-order-in-a-specific-format)

Answer (score 0):

Use a Queue to do level traverse.
You can see my implementation: https://github.com/shaogbi/Java/blob/master/datastructure/MyBinaryTree.java
see `levelTraverse` function.