# Print a Tree By Level (with a simple method)

Tags: java

PS: This is NOT HOMEWORK. And I didn't understand the other question answer's, otherwise I wouldnt be opening a new one...

I'm trying to print this tree:

```
            3
          /   \
        7       2
      /   \       \
    0       9      11
  /   \           /  \
1       2       6      4
```

As a level order output:

```
3
7 2
0 9 11
1 2 6 4
```

The problem is my code can only print trees like this: 3 7 2 0 9 11 1 2 64, which is the same as the last numbers but without a paragraph or '\n'. I can't seem to find an easy way to do this (preferencially without using foreach). Someone told me I should create a variable: 'level' on the tree that classifies in which level the node is, but how can I even classify the levels?
Can you help me?

```
public void largura() { //just an auxiliar method to call 'larguras'
   larguras(root);
   System.out.println();
}

private void larguras(Node t) {
   LinkedList<Node> f = new LinkedList<Node>();
   Node r;
   f.add(t);

   while (!f.isEmpty()) {
       r=f.remove();
       if (r!=root) System.out.print(" ");
       System.out.print(r.value);
       if (r.left != null) f.add(r.left);
       if (r.right != null) f.add(r.right);
   }
```

}

Comment: Make the problem simpler (for yourself).  How do you print a tree with one node?  How do you print a tree with one root and two children?  What do the spacings look like?

Comment: I already know that. The problem is not on that, it's on trying to find out in which level does a specific Node belongs!

Comment: It's really unclear why you say this isn't a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241513/java-printing-a-binary-tree-using-level-order-in-a-specific-format) -- as far as I can tell you're asking about exactly the same problem. If you have a different, more specific problem, ask a different question. Otherwise, I suggest studying the answers to the other question until you understand them.

Answer (score -1):

Hmmm... Would something like this work?

```
 //Prints the tree in level order
  public void printTree(){
    printTree(root);
  }

 public void printTree(TreeNode tmpRoot){

//If the first node isn't null....continue on
if(tmpRoot != null){

    Queue<TreeNode> currentLevel = new LinkedList<TreeNode>(); //Queue that holds the nodes on the current level
    Queue<TreeNode> nextLevel = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();     //Queue the stores the nodes for the next level

    int treeHeight = height(tmpRoot);     //Stores the height of the current tree
    int levelTotal = 0;  //keeps track of the total levels printed so we don't  pass the height and print a billion "null"s

    //put the root on the currnt level's queue
    currentLevel.add(tmpRoot);

    //while there is still another level to print and we haven't gone past the tree's height
    while(!currentLevel.isEmpty()&& (levelTotal< treeHeight)){

        //Print the next node on the level, add its childen to the next level's queue, and dequeue the node...do this until the current level has been printed
        while(!currentLevel.isEmpty()){

            //Print the current value
            System.out.print(currentLevel.peek().getValue()+" ");

            //If there is a left pointer, put the node on the nextLevel's stack. If there is no ponter, add a node with a null value to the next level's stack
            tmpRoot = currentLevel.peek().getLeft();
            if(tmpRoot != null)
                nextLevel.add(tmpRoot);
            else
                nextLevel.add(new TreeNode(null));

            //If there is a right pointer, put the node on the nextLevel's stack. If there is no ponter, add a node with a null value to the next level's stack
            tmpRoot = currentLevel.remove().getRight();
            if(tmpRoot != null)
                nextLevel.add(tmpRoot);
            else
                nextLevel.add(new TreeNode(null));

        }//end while(!currentLevel.isEmpty())

        //populate the currentLevel queue with items from the next level
        while(!nextLevel.isEmpty()){
            currentLevel.add(nextLevel.remove());
        }

        //Print a blank line to show height
        System.out.println("");

        //flag that we are working on the next level
        levelTotal++;

    }//end while(!currentLevel.isEmpty())

}//end if(tmpRoot != null)

}//end method printTree

public int height(){
    return height(getRoot());
  }

public int height(TreeNode tmpRoot){

if (tmpRoot == null)
    return 0;
int leftHeight = height(tmpRoot.getLeft());
int rightHeight = height(tmpRoot.getRight());

if(leftHeight >= rightHeight)
    return leftHeight + 1;
else
    return rightHeight + 1;
```

Or perhaps something like this:

```
 public void BFSPrint()
{
    Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<Node>();
    q.offer(root);
    BFSPrint(q);
}

private void BFSPrint(Queue<Node> q)
{
if(q.isEmpty())
    return;
int qLen = q.size(),i=0;
 /*limiting it to q size when it is passed, 
   this will make it print in next lines. if we use iterator instead, 
   we will again have same output as question, because iterator 
   will end only q empties*/
while(i<qLen) 
    {
    Node current = q.remove();
    System.out.print(current.data+" ");
    if(current.left!=null)
        q.offer(current.left);
    if(current.right!=null)
        q.offer(current.right);
    i++;
}
System.out.println();
BFSPrint(q);

}
```

Essentially you are doing something like this:
http://leetcode.com/2010/09/printing-binary-tree-in-level-order.html

The code above will not work for a tree of more than 3 levels that's for you to figure out. 
@ commenter / -1'er I gave an example so they can play with it. It would appear that this is either homework or a sample exercise and I find playing with the code itself is more helpful to learning. Thats why I gave multiple implementations.

Comment: All code and no explanation is a bit...depressing.

Comment: A bit of explanation and some pseudo-code would be of much more help than such a long example.  Writing the solution will also help the OP learn.

Comment: It appeared to me to be a homework problem so I didn't want to give the full solution in the case of potential academic dishonesty. But I gave resources to 3 strong examples for comparison.

Comment: it's not homework, i'm not even studying.